# Why are there 3 pts entries in /dev/pts when w only shows 1?

Tags: tty

In the directory /dev/pts I see 3 pts instances as shown in the screenshot below however when I run the command `w` I only see 1 instance of pts. Why is that?

/dev/pts

[image]

`w`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`w` does not deal with tty devices directly – it only displays those registered in `/run/utmp`. Programs (such as terminal emulators, or remote login daemons) usually register themselves to become visible in the `w`/`who` list, but *are not required* in any way to do so.

For example, the `screen` utility deregisters itself when you detach, despite keeping the pty devices allocated. A popular replacement of screen, `tmux`, never uses utmp – it isn't programmed to use it. Some terminal emulators do not register themselves simply due to lack of privileges (the program needs to have "setgid utmp" set). There could be more reasons, and not all of them malicious.

Use **`lsof`** or **`fuser`** to see all processes having those ptys open:

```
sudo fuser -v /dev/pts/*

sudo lsof /dev/pts/*
```